# [window terminal][vim] cursor doesn't move and typing is overlapped before right arrow or enter

Tags: c++, terminal, window

[window terminal][vim] cursor doesn't move and typing is overlapped before right arrow or enter

I think it's better to show in video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxeePuQvI4o&feature=youtu.be

I often get this bug when I failed the compile(just my thoughts)
and it becomes okay when I restart the computer(not window terminal)

how can I fix it?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.   If I try to move it twice then click in any other window/program the terminal window moves.  To get the cursor to work I have to click twice and click out and then back in.    It is also sometimes stating there is a problem loading a font but doesn't give me the option to change the font.